# Бот заносит в переменную команду, как это исправить? Aiogram ТЕЛЕГРАМ

Tags: python, aiogram

Я делаю кликер у меня есть обычный клик, баланс, вип клик через кнопку

Но я хочу так же сделать что то на подобие админ клика, что бы когда админ писал команду /aclick228
после чего писал нужно число и бот заносил это число в переменную count

Я попытался что то такое сделать, но бот заносит в переменную текс самой команды /aclick228

Как это исправить?

Вот код:

```
    elif message.text == 'aclick228':
countadm = message.text
count += countadm
return count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте интрегрировать в Ваш код следующее решение.

Чтобы получить число, которое администратор вводит после команды `/aclick228`, Вы можете разделить строку на две части с помощью метода `split()`. Первая часть будет содержать саму команду `/aclick228`, а вторая будет содержать `число`, которое вы (или другой администратор) вводите.

В этом примере метод `startswith()` используется для проверки, начинается ли текст сообщения с команды `/aclick228`. Если это так, то текст разделяется на две части с помощью метода `split()`, используя пробел в качестве разделителя.

Код:

```python
elif message.text.startswith('/aclick228'):
    countadm = int(message.text.split()[1]) # преобразовываем вторую часть в целое число с помощью функции int()
    count += countadm
    return count
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ ПОМАГЛО!!!!

Comment: Чудесно, успехов Вам :)